# Generate input handler via jQuery for xmlhttprequest json data in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamics-crm-2011, jquery-events

I'm struggling with dynamic generation of buttons over a JSON array.

Stripped-down code is this (aim is to build a table based on the data, nothing fancy yet, I'm not yet proficient at this):

```
$.ajax({
    /* type, content, etc. removed */
    success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
        var target = $('myContainerDiv');
        var result = data.d.results;

        var $table = $('<table />');
        for(var i=0;i < results.length; i++) {
            var $row = $('<tr />');
            var $cell = $('<td />');
            var $button = $('<input />').attr({ type: 'button', value: 'Edit', name: 'btn' + i });
            $button.click(function () {

                // **
                // In a .NET environment, this would become a closure
                // I suspect this is the offending bit of code
                //

                alert(results[i].name);

            };

            $cell.append($button);
            $row.append($cell);
            $table.append($row);
        }

        $target.append($table);
    },
    /* error etc. removed*/
});
```

I basically want a column filled with buttons, each one would popup the value of a field from the array I get from my `$.ajax` call.

Buttons actually show up, but they do not react to clicking, and I see no runtime error in the F12 tools console. This is probably due to the fact that this script is part of the configuration page for a Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Solution, but other than that, I'm sure the AJAX call goes on OK (I tried making it print out data, and I can see it).

**UPDATE**

Referencing `i` inside the click handler was the offending line indeed: changed the code like this made things work as I was expecting:

```
var $button = $('<input />').attr({ type: 'button', value: 'Edit', name: 'btn' + results[i].name });
$button.click(function () {
    // 'i' value is NOT what I thought it was !
    alert(this.name.substring(3,this.name.length));
    // I found out in the meanwhile that 'this' references the event source
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have several syntax errors in your code and it may not be running at all:

1. if the ID of your div container is `myContainerDiv`, to get the target you need to do `$('#myContainerDiv')`
2. you create a `result` varialbe, but you use a `results` variable
3. you're not closing the parentesis in the `$button.click`
4. you're adding everything to `$target` but is defined as `target`

Now the actual problem may be, as you say, the closure, remember that you close over variables not values, so when you execute the button click handler, `i` has a value of `results.length`, so you are out of bounds by that time.

You could try to store the `results` objects elsewhere, extract the Id of the object your looking for from the button (you're naming then `'btn'+i`) and then access the `name` property that way.

Comment: I kinda messed up the syntax while rewriting the code (couldn't copy-paste, it's much longer with alerts and longer names...). However, the pointed out fact about the `i` variable being equal to `results.length` sounds like the real issue. Will check it out.

Comment: Got rid of `i` in the handler, and things started working. I'll edit the question to point it out.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you didn't close the .click() bracket.

Try...

```
$button.click(function () {
    alert(results[i].name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ...

```
$.ajax({
/* type, content, etc. removed */
success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
    var $target = $('#myContainerDiv'),
        results = data.d.results,
        $table = $target.append('<table />').children('table:last-child'), $trSet = $([]);
    for(var i=0; i < results.length; i++) {
        $trSet = $trSet.add(
            $([
                '<tr><td>',
                $('<input type="button" value="edit" name="btn'+i+'" rel="'+results[i].name+'" />').wrap('<div />').html(),
                '</td></tr>'
            ].join(''))
        );
    }       
    // Using Event delegation ... Only one handler is attached to the DOM.
    $table.append($trSet).click(function(e){
        var $t = $(e.target);

        if( $t.is('input[type="button"]') ){
            alert($t.attr('rel'));
        }
        // choose to return false whether to prevent event bubbling up the DOM or not
        // return false;
    });     
  },
   /* error etc. removed*/
});
```